# android counter error says temp might not have be initialized

Tags: android

I am trying to create value from starting from 1/2/3/4/5 etc
output will be temp1/temp2/temp3 and so on. But it is giving error.

The error says temp might not have be initialized

```
 button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = 0;
                count++;
String temp;
                temp + count;
                list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                HashMap<String,String> temp= new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "Ankit Kariaazzzz");
                temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "Male");
                temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "22");
                temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Unmarried");
                list.add(temp);

                ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity2Activity.this, list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
```

Also when I try and add new item  all other remaining item gets removed ?

Comment: set `String temp="";`  you have two `temp` variable of two different type in the same scope is it possible?

Comment: `temp + count;` not a statement you should give some variable at left side `temp=temp+count;`

Comment: I would suggest starting with a basic program first. There are multiple problems in your code. 1) Variable not initialized. 2) What is temp + count suppose to do? 3) There are 2 variables named temp in the same scope

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of error in your code.

1. uninitialized variable `temp`
2. two `temp` with variable in same scope.[image]
3. `temp + count;` not a statement.

Comment: sasikumar this works am going to se now if i can add item mulipul times rather then removing current list ,,,,,,,,,,,, Rustam thanks also

Comment: all the code is working but now when i click the button only 1 item remains in list rather then adding more and more because am creating  int+1/2/3/4/5    ?

Comment: declare `temp` as class variable instead of local variable since it is overwritten each time you click so last value is showing.

Comment: Rustam how do i declare as class variable ?

Comment: ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity2Activity.this, list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);          this is not letting me add more items it just removes current items

Answer (score 0):

```
 initialized  the variable temp 

  String temp="";
```

And

```
  temp + count;  change into  
  temp=temp+count;
```

**two temp** (string ,HashMap)with variable so change anyone as **temp1**

Comment: i added   String temp;
                temp="";
                temp + count;             i get   ( not a statement ) on temp + count;

Comment: public class MainActivity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    String temp="";     oncreate is below this   still i get    not a statement ? on  temp+count;

Comment: temp + count;  change into  temp=temp+count;

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because there is no object of String to which temp can refer. Hence you need to create an object by, say
`String temp="";`
This will create an object of String and hence initialize the `temp`
Also, maybe this is what you mean by `temp+count`:
`temp = temp + count`
Another one, use a different name for HashMap.